Moderator Agreement notice disappeared without dismissing it
There was a banner with a new moderator agreement information.

I didn't dismiss it (and I didn't yet accepted new Agreement), but it has disappeared now.
Is it expected behavior? Actually I'm waiting for translation to be available, but now it's possible to reproduce it.

Did you by any chance accept it? This might explain why you don't see the message.

@ShadowWizard of course there is a chance by do it accidentally or my pet did this when device was unlocked. Unfortunately I don't know about it. But if there is an evidence from other mods that this banner is still visible for them, then we could say that very likely something wrong in my case.

Yep, same for me. And on both sites I moderate. I didn't dismiss it, but it's gone.

Not for me, though, it's still there.

I haven't accepted it yet either and the banner is gone for me too. Can confirm.

And another silly question, the new agreement still exists? They might have just zapped it, hence no need to show a banner anymore. :/

@ShadowWizard You can check it yourself, MSE one is here
